How can I install the aiohttp and pycryptodome?
I'm having trouble installing the aiohttp and pycryptodome libraries, because there are many errors. I will provide you with a portion of the errors, I am waiting for your help, Terminal: Termux, Python version: 3.11.9
Error Pycryptodome:

aarch64-linux-android-clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall
-fstack-protector-strong -O3 -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -fPIC -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DPYCRYPTO_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DSYS_BITS=64 -DLTC_NO_ASM -DHAVE_UINT128 -DHAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN -Isrc/ -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.11 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/MD2.o
aarch64-linux-android-clang -shared
-L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -fopenmp -static-openmp -fno-openmp-implicit-rpath -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,--no-as-needed,-landroid-support,--as-needed -L/home/builder/.termux-build/_cache/android-r26b-api-24-v3/sysroot/usr/lib
-L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -fopenmp -static-openmp -fno-openmp-implicit-rpath -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,--no-as-needed,-landroid-support,--as-needed -L/home/builder/.termux-build/_cache/android-r26b-api-24-v3/sysroot/usr/lib
build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/MD2.o
-L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/Crypto/Hash/_MD2.abi3.so
aarch64-linux-android-clang: error: unknown argument:
'-fno-openmp-implicit-rpath'
aarch64-linux-android-clang: error: unknown argument:
'-fno-openmp-implicit-rpath'                              error:
command
'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-android-clang'
failed with exit code 1        [end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
problem with pip.                            ERROR: Failed building
wheel for pycryptodome         Failed to build aiohttp pycryptodome
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, pycryptodome, which is
required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Error Aiohttp:
creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/aiohttp aarch64-linux-android-clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -fPIC -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.11 -c aiohttp/_websocket.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/aiohttp/_websocket.o                     aarch64-linux-android-clang -shared -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -fopenmp -static-openmp -fno-openmp-implicit-rpath -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,--no-as-needed,-landroid-support,--as-needed -L/home/builder/.termux-build/_cache/android-r26b-api-24-v3/sysroot/usr/lib -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -fopenmp -static-openmp -fno-openmp-implicit-rpath -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,--no-as-needed,-landroid-support,--as-needed -L/home/builder/.termux-build/_cache/android-r26b-api-24-v3/sysroot/usr/lib build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/aiohttp/_websocket.o -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -lpython3.11 -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/aiohttp/_websocket.cpython-311.so                                       aarch64-linux-android-clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-openmp-implicit-rpath'                              aarch64-linux-android-clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-openmp-implicit-rpath'                              error: command '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-android-clang' failed with exit code 1        [end of output] note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.                            ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp Building wheel for pycryptodome (pyproject.toml) ...error error: subprocess-exited-with-error
I wanted to install the aiohttp and pycryptodome libraries, but I encountered an error.
